# How can I stop the Select component from closing when I clicked one of its item(Input element) - react antd

Tags: javascript, reactjs, antd

I am using `antd(3.23.4)`. I have a `Select` component and I want to avoid it to close when I click one of its Option(Input element). Had been successful avoiding to close it however, cannot focus on the Input element when I clicked it. I think this is because I wrapped it on a div and used a `preventDefault()` on the div - which stops immediately when I clicked the Input element. I've searched some of the issues on the antd's github but no luck. Here is a sample of my code:

```
            <Select
              dropdownRender={menu => (
                <React.Fragment>
                   {menu}      
                   <div onMouseDown={e => e.preventDefault()}>
                       <Input type="number" key="others" addonBefore="Others: " /> 
                   </div>
                </React.Fragment>
                                        
                  )} >
                    <Option key="bar" value="bar">
                        bar
                    </Option>
                </Select>
```

The problem here is that I can't click/focus the input. So that I can type in it.

Need help. Please advise. Thank you in advance for those who will answer :)

Comment: are you trying for multiselect ?

Comment: Hello DILEEP, I'm not trying for multiselect.

Comment: So single select but the menu should be persistent isn't

Comment: yes the menu should be persistent. So if i dont want the `bar` option, I can type to the input element what value I want.

Comment: Then in that case always the menu will be open, at which condition it will be closed

Answer (score 0):

We have a `size=""` attribute in select component(tag) in html [Select Attributes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/select).
This make sure how many options inside the selectbox is visible at a time so u may do it like this....

```
<select
            id="select"
            name="catagory"
            onChange={(e) => handleChange(e)}
            onClick={() => addSize()}
          >
            *.....Your Options....*
</select>



const addSize = () => {
  const selectBox = document.getElementById("select");
  selectBox.addEventListener("click", selectBox.setAttribute("size", 10));
};
```

Comment: thanks for answering Yog. I think the size is not the problem here? Since I rendered it properly. my problem here is that I cannot click the Input element within the Select component.